# Rejecting a Promise with another new Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Im playing around with promises and i wanted a way of rejecting the promise inside of a then callback. So this is done by either calling throw return or return Promise.reject();. So far so good. You can accomplish this by also calling new Promise.reject();  withou a return.

Can someone explain why does this work?

```
new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res(200);
  }, 2000);
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log("ok1");
    new Promise.reject();
    // return Promise.reject(); 
  .then(() => {
    console.log("ok2");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("error");
  });
```

Comment: Cause `new Promise` does not have a `.reject()` method, so its a syntax error, which causes the promise to reject.

Comment: Why you call a new promise and reject it? why you call then after reject?!

Comment: @JonasWilms it's actually `new (Promise.reject)` that is being interpreted.

Comment: @GeorgePaouris Each console will see the error

Comment: @vlaz a right, `Promise.reject` doesnt have promise capabilities though https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-newpromisecapability

Comment: @JonasWilms yes, you're right, it was just a different reason why it was failing, it wasn't `(new Promise).reject()` but `new (Promise.reject)()` that failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
new Promise.reject()
```

Your code throws an exception. Exceptions cause promises to be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Promise.reject` is not a constructor, this code works fine:

```js
new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res(200);
  }, 2000);
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('ok1')
    Promise.reject('error!')
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log("ok2");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("error");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

New Promise.reject throws an error so the code jumps to the catch section with the following error : `Promise.reject is not a constructor`

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('OK');
  }, 2000);
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    new Promise.reject(); 
    })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('error' ,err.message);
  });
```